# How to add an array value to new FormData?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On form submission I'm using jQuery to gather data including files and creating a FormData Object of the form values using:

```
var formData = new FormData($("form#formid")[0]);
```

but how can I add another value and it's key to this FormData Object?

Comment: @Esailija I need to get the contents of the form including FILES to post with ajax, didn't think `serialize()` could handle files?

Comment: I was confused because you said "array". I edited it to be what I think you are asking.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var formData = new FormData($("form#formid")[0]);
formData.append("key", "value")
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over all the fields in the form and add them to the `FormData` quite easily this way :

```
var formData = new FormData();
$("form#edit-account").serializeArray().forEach(function(field) {
  formData.append(field.name, field.value)
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [FormData.set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set).

> The difference between FormData.set and append() is that if the
>   specified key already exists, FormData.set will overwrite all existing
>   values with the new one, whereas append() will append the new value
>   onto the end of the existing set of values.

**Syntax**:

```
formData.set(name, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( 'form' ).submit(function ( e ) {
var data;

data = new FormData();
data.append( 'file', $( '#file' )[0].files[0] );

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://hacheck.tel.fer.hr/xml.pl',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function ( data ) {
        alert( data );
    }
});

e.preventDefault();
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = new FormData(),
    fields = $("#myForm").serializeArray();

$.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
    data.append(field.name, field.value);
});
```