# HTML5 formData.append() passing field names and values as single parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have to append some information in my JS with form data. Something like..

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('photo', photo_data );
form_data.append('customer_id', customer_id);
form_data.append('year_name', year_name);
```

As we can see I have used .append thrice for three information. I tried something like this and did not work as .append() expects two parameters(field name and value) and not object.

```
var data = {'photo': photo_data, 'customer_id': customer_id, 'year_name', year_name};
form_data.append(data);
```

I wish to know if there is some way to pass multiple field names and values in a single line. Thanks!

Comment: In first line you are using `formdata` and then you start using `form_data`?

Comment: Sure, if all your fields are in the same `<form>`, you can directly call `new FormData(yourForm)`

Comment: Add Array values to FormData is described here .. [How to add an array value to new FormData?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208488/how-to-add-an-array-value-to-new-formdata)

Comment: Ps: if all you got is this object, you can also simply iterate over your object's keys : `Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k){form_data.append(k, data[k]);})`

Comment: Sorry, a typo @Mike . Edited the question.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido and Roshan  for your suggestions.