# How to send files and text with ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code that uploads files to server but there is still one thing that I don't know how to fix.

```
var form_data = new FormData();
    var ins = document.getElementById('upload-computer').files.length;
        for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
            form_data.append("files[]", document.getElementById('upload-computer').files[x]);
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload_file.php',
                dataType: 'text', 
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function (res) {
                    if(res){alert(res);}
                    console.log(form_data)
                }
                    });
```

My problem is that in data part of ajax request if I add another value like this:

```
data: form_data + '&name='+someVar,
```

...it won't work. How to make this work? And I don't use form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an array value to new FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208488/how-to-add-an-array-value-to-new-formdata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add the new elements to the formData object like this

```
formData.append("name", "someVar");
```